# OpenGL quality difference between glDrawElements and immediate mode

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I'm working for the first time on a 3D project (actually, I'm programming a Bullet Physics integration in a Quartz Composer plug-in), and as I try to optimize my rendering method, I began to use glDrawElements instead of the direct access to vertices by glVertex3d...

I'm very surprised by the result. I didn't check if it is actually quicker, but I tried on this very simple scene below. And, from my point of view, the rendering is really better in immediate mode.

The "draw elements" method keep showing the edges of the triangles and a very ugly shadow on the cube.

I would really appreciate some information on this difference, and may be a way to keep quality with glDrawElements. I'm aware that it could really be a mistake of mines...

**Immediate mode**
[image]

**DrawElements**
[image]

The vertices, indices and normals are computed the same way in the two method. Here are the 2 codes.

**Immediate mode**

```
glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
    int si=36;
    for (int i=0;i<si;i+=3)
    {
        const btVector3& v1 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i]];;
        const btVector3& v2 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i+1]];
        const btVector3& v3 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i+2]];


        btVector3 normal = (v1-v3).cross(v1-v2);
        normal.normalize ();
        glNormal3f(-normal.getX(),-normal.getY(),-normal.getZ());
        glVertex3f (v1.x(), v1.y(), v1.z());
        glVertex3f (v2.x(), v2.y(), v2.z());
        glVertex3f (v3.x(), v3.y(), v3.z());

    }
    glEnd();
```

**glDrawElements**

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(btVector3), &(normalsArray[0].getX()));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(btVector3), &(verticesArray[0].getX()));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indicesArray);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Thank you.

### **EDIT**

Here is the code for the vertices / indices / normals

```
GLubyte indicesArray[] = {
        0,1,2,
        3,2,1,
        4,0,6,
        6,0,2,
        5,1,4,
        4,1,0,
        7,3,1,
        7,1,5,
        5,4,7,
        7,4,6,
        7,2,3,
        7,6,2 };

    btVector3 verticesArray[] = {
        btVector3(halfExtent[0], halfExtent[1], halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(-halfExtent[0], halfExtent[1], halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(halfExtent[0], -halfExtent[1], halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(-halfExtent[0], -halfExtent[1], halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(halfExtent[0], halfExtent[1], -halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(-halfExtent[0], halfExtent[1], -halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(halfExtent[0], -halfExtent[1], -halfExtent[2]),
        btVector3(-halfExtent[0], -halfExtent[1], -halfExtent[2])
    };

    indicesCount = sizeof(indicesArray);
    verticesCount = sizeof(verticesArray);


    btVector3 normalsArray[verticesCount];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount * 3; i += 3)
    {
        const btVector3& v1 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i]];;
        const btVector3& v2 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i+1]];
        const btVector3& v3 = verticesArray[indicesArray[i+2]];

        btVector3 normal = (v1-v3).cross(v1-v2);
        normal.normalize ();

        normalsArray[j] = btVector3(-normal.getX(), -normal.getY(), -normal.getZ());

        j++;
    }
```

Comment: What you call "Direct Access" is actually the *slow* track and detached from the GPU. To get the maximum performance you want to place the vertex data in a vertex array located in GPU's own memory. (Vertex Buffer Object). Also immediate mode has been removed from modern versions of OpenGL.

Comment: Visual quality has nothing to do with immediate / programmable pipelines.Both end up on GPU

Comment: @datenwolf I learned a lot with this forum thread, as an OpenGL newbie. Now, I cache the vertex data in C arrays and call them with glDrawElements. I'll try to integrate VBOs in my program but for the moment it seems quite complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and will) achieve the exact same results with immediate mode and vertex array based rendering. Your images suggest that you got your normals wrong. As you did not include the code with which you create your arrays, I can only guess what might be wrong. One thing I could imagine: you are using one normal per triangle, so in the normal array, you have to repeat that normal for each vertex.

You should be aware that a vertex in the GL is not just the position (which you specify via `glVertex` in immediate mode), but the set of *all* attributes like position, normals, texcoords and so on. So if you have a mesh where an end point is part of different triangles, this is only one vertex if all attributes are shared, not just the position. In your case, the normals are per triangle, so you will need different vertices (sharing position with some other vertices, but using a different normal) per triangle.

Comment: Thank you ! I added the code used to "generate" my vertices, indices, and normals.

Comment: @L'angeCarasuelo: That just confirms my guesswork. Your VA code is not equivalent to the immediate mode code. First of all: what is 'j' and why is it never increased? But the main problem is just what I already said: look at the first two triangles: (0,1,2) and (3,2,1). 1 and 2 are shared between those two primitives. But they have to be **different** vertices as far as the GL is concerned - one copy of vertex 1 and 2 for each primitive - since they use different normal vectors.

Comment: I edited the post with j. Don't know where it had disappeared :-/ I undestand that it is quite a mess, I'm not really sure of my "j" now... Could you please explain ? I don't understand how to organize my vertices / indices... Do you mean that I have to double each vertex that has a different normal (in fact, I guess that I'll have to send 3 vertices per triangle, isn't it ?)

Comment: @L'angeCarasuelo: Yes, you have to "duplicate" that data. But you don't have to end up with 3 different vertices per triangle. E.g., look at the sides of a cube. A cube has 8 corners and 6 sides. Each side has its own normal, so you just need 6*4=24 vertices. FOr one side, you need two trinagles, and not 6 different vertices, but only 4, as 2 vertices per side can be shared by the two triangles. Of course, not sharing these and doing a full "duplication" (36 vertices for the cube) will also work, but is a waste of ressources.

Comment: Thanks again ! I think I'm beginning to understand. I'm really not clear with how OpenGL "link" vertices, normals and indices...

Comment: @L'angeCarasuelo: As I already said: GL does not link "vertices", normals and indices. A vertex **is** a set of attributes (like position, normal, texcoords, color, whatever). And an index references just one vertex. And this reflects the way GPUs work. In immediate mode, that fact was just hidden from you. There, the GL just has one "current" vertex whose attribute values are changed using `glNormal` or `glColor` etc, `glVertex` was just special in that it not only updates one attribute - the position - but actually also submits that whole vertex (at least conceptually).

Comment: OK ! I do understand now ! Thank you for your patience. Now the immediate mode seems kind of weird in such a system...

Answer (score 2):

> I began to use glDrawElements

Good!

> instead of the direct access to vertices by glVertex3d...

There's nothing "direct" about immediate mode. In fact it's as far away from the GPU as you can get (on modern GPU architectures).

> I'm very surprised by the result. I didn't check if it is actually quicker, but I tried on this very simple scene below. And, from my point of view, the rendering is really better with the direct access method.

Actually its several orders of magnitudes slower. Each and every glVertex call causes the overhead of a context switch. Also a GPU needs larger batches of data to work efficiently, so glVertex calls first fill a buffer created ad-hoc.

Your immediate code segment must be actually understand as following

```
    glNormal3f(-normal.getX(),-normal.getY(),-normal.getZ());
    glVertex3f (v1.x(), v1.y(), v1.z());

    // implicit copy of the glNormal supplied above
    glVertex3f (v2.x(), v2.y(), v2.z());

    // implicit copy of the glNormal supplied above
    glVertex3f (v3.x(), v3.y(), v3.z());
```

The reason for that is, that a vertex is not just a position, but the whole combination of its attributes. And when working with vertex arrays you must supply the full attribute vector to form a valid vertex.

Comment: +1 for immediate mode derating.I always wonder what causes people still trying to use it these days...

Comment: @MichaelIV: I blame bad tutorials and lack of programming experience on the side of people actually using it; for people who are not (yet) accustomed to think in data structures it usually easier to think in programming "laudry lists". Kind of the same mental barrier (experienced) imperative programmers face when confronted with pure functional programming.